# Firebase UI login email list source, where are they from and can I delete them

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using the firebase UI login on Android from https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android, my question is: how or where does this library retrieve all my previous emails like this one picture. Can i delete some of them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email addresses are acquired from the [Smart Lock for Passwords](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/package-summary) API, by starting an Intent returned from [CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/CredentialsApi.html#getHintPickerIntent). The data itself comes from three sources:

- Accounts which are added to the device, found in [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).
- Email addresses directly associated with the user's Google accounts (as found in https://myaccount.google.com/privacy#personalinfo)
- Email addresses that have been saved for any app or site, using the Smart Lock for Passwords API or in Chrome. To see the complete list for this, look at https://passwords.google.com

Most of the email addresses are likely coming from credentials you saved in Chrome. To be clear, an app using the Smart Lock for Passwords API cannot see all these email addresses - it only receives an email address that the user explicitly taps on.

For an overview of the functionality and behavior of Smart Lock for Passwords, see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/).